# Spring- How to configure OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor for multiple entityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Spring- How to configure OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor for multiple entityManager in my application?

This is how I have already configured it for one..

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor">  
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: Add multiple interceptors, one for each `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: Thanks.,..I will let u know after trying..but r u sure that we can define two interceptors and that second one is not going to affect my first interceptor?